# Chrony - Synchronize the date and time of all host computers in a network without internet connection

Tags: networking, date, synchronization, ntp, chrony

I have two machines,

1. host A with IP 192.168.0.1
2. host B with IP 192.168.0.2

They connected to the same network and I would like to set the date and time of machine B to match those of machine A. While I can set up the machines with an internet connection initially, they will not have access to it once deployed and they will be rebooted every day.

**Current Approach using Chrony**
[Reference](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/network-ntp).

*This configuration is not correct*, based on some test results, the synchronization succeeds when the NTP server has an internet connection and fails otherwise.

Do you have any advice or suggestions for configuring them effectively?

**Machine A - Configured as NTP server**

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install chrony
sudo vim /etc/chrony/chrony.conf
```

Used this configuration to set up the NTP server

```
confdir /etc/chrony/conf.d
pool ntp.ubuntu.com        iburst maxsources 4
pool 0.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org iburst maxsources 1
pool 1.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org iburst maxsources 1
pool 2.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org iburst maxsources 2
allow 192.168.0.0/24
sourcedir /run/chrony-dhcp
sourcedir /etc/chrony/sources.d
keyfile /etc/chrony/chrony.keys
driftfile /var/lib/chrony/chrony.drift
ntsdumpdir /var/lib/chrony
logdir /var/log/chrony
maxupdateskew 100.0
rtcsync
makestep 1 3
leapsectz right/UTC
```

Restarted the chrony service, checked that was running and enabled it to start on boot

```
sudo systemctl restart chrony
sudo systemctl status chrony
CTRL+C
sudo systemctl enable chrony
```

**Machine B - Configured as Chrony Client**

Synced the date and time with a pool of servers and set the 192.168.0.1

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install chrony
sudo vim /etc/chrony/chrony.conf
```

Used the following configuration file

```
pool 192.168.0.1 iburst prefer
keyfile /etc/chrony/chrony.keys
driftfile /var/lib/chrony/chrony.drift
logdir /var/log/chrony
log measurements statistics tracking
maxupdateskew 100.0
rtcsync
makestep 1.0 3
```

Restarted, checked the service and enabled it at startup

```
sudo systemctl restart chrony
sudo systemctl status chrony
CTRL+C
sudo systemctl enable chrony
```

**Update**
If I manually synchronize the time, I get the following error **No suitable source for synchronisation**.

```
sudo systemctl stop chrony 
sudo chronyd -d 'server 192.168.0.1 iburst'
2023-03-15T15:54:55Z chronyd version 3.5 starting (+CMDMON +NTP +REFCLOCK +RTC +PRIVDROP +SCFILTER +SIGND +ASYNCDNS +SECHASH +IPV6 -DEBUG)
2023-03-15T15:54:55Z Initial frequency -36.773 ppm
2023-03-15T15:55:03Z No suitable source for synchronisation
2023-03-15T15:55:03Z chronyd exiting
```

**Update 2**

If I connect the NTP server to internet, then the synchronization succeeds.

Comment: Best advice? Get a cheap sbc and a cheap gps with PPS, and use that as a time server.

Comment: Thanks Bib for your input. Actually one of the two host has a dgnss setup. I am parsing and getting the number of milliseconds from 1970. Ex: 1682600940 
Now I just need to share this info with other hosts on the local network using a time server, which is where the question comes from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the directive `local` in the server config file for it to synchronize on its own when there is no internet. Typically,  you might use `local stratum 8` to say it is less good than a remote ntp server that might be stratum 2 or 3. This stops the local clock being preferred over the internet clock source. If the server has a hardware time source like a gps then look at the `refclock` directive to see if it can be configured in too.

Comment: Thanks @meuh for your answer. This directive allowed the other hosts on the network to sync their time with the NTP server

Comment: I have noticed that if the time on the NTP server changes, the clients do not update their time straight away. Is there a way to increase the update frequency to make the synchronization quicker?

Comment: Generally, we don't want the time to change suddenly, except at boot, so we expect the server not to say it is synched until it has a reliable source. If you have some gps device setting the time and causing the big step, then you should probably not start chronyd on the server until the gps has updated the system time. You already have a `makestep` entry on the client. You could change it to `makestep 1 -1` to let the client do step changes later on.